# Can "at large" be used with Native Americans?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I want to describe Native American peoples that escaped from the US soldiers. Can I say:

> The Apache tribes escaped from the US army and stayed at large.

I see example sentences use prisoners. Is it correct with this usage too?

Answer (score 5):

Probably not.

The dictionary (oxford, via google) gives this definition:

> (especially of a criminal or dangerous animal) at liberty; escaped or not yet captured.

"At large" implies that the Apache people were like criminals, which is an implication you probably want to avoid.

Comment: Considering that the soldiers had taken the Apache's freedom, it might be suitable to use the word *free* to describe the state of the Apache.  *They escaped and remained free from the authority of the Army,* is probably closer to how you would want to word something like this.

Comment: Indeed. I think of a wanted criminal still out in the world committing infamies.